# Undefined variables in html templates for MailApp

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to send an HTML email using MailApp. 
This is the table where I will pull the data from:

[image]

After reading the documentations and posts on SO, I am still unable to pin point why the email sent out is showing undefined in the variables part.

[image]

Would appreciate if someone can point me to the right direction.

These are my codes:

**sendHtmlEmail.gs**

```
function sendEmails() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();

    var quotaLeft = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
    if((lastRow-1) > quotaLeft){
     Browser.msgBox("You have " + quotaLeft + " email quota left and you're trying to send " + (lastRow-1) + " emails. Emails were not sent.")
    } else {
      for (var row = 2; row <= lastRow; row++){
        var currentEmail = ss.getRange(row, 4).getValue(); 
        var currentContact = ss.getRange(row, 3).getValue();
        var currentNewSize = ss.getRange(row,8).getValue();
        var currentSub = ss.getRange(row, 9).getValue();
        var returnData = [currentContact, currentNewSize, currentSub];
        var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('htmlTemplate');

        html.data = returnData;
        var template = html.evaluate().getContent();
        var subjectLine = "Important notice";
        MailApp.sendEmail({to: currentEmail, subject: subjectLine, htmlBody: template}); 
       } //close for loop
        Browser.msgBox("You have successfully sent " + (lastRow-1) + " emails.")
     } //close else statement 
}
```

**htmlTemplate.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><base target="_top"></head><body style="text-align: center;font-family: Arial;">
  <div id="center" style="width:300px;border: 2px dotted grey;background:#ececec;margin:25px;margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;padding:15px;"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4f/Simple_Alert.svg/600px-Simple_Alert.svg.png"
width="180" style="margin:10px 0px"><br /><div style=" border: 2px dotted grey;background:white;margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto;
padding:10px;"><h2>Alert</h2><h3>Important Notice <br /><br />
+ <?= data.currentContact ?> + '<br />' + <?= data.currentNewSize ?> + '<br />' + <?= data.currentSub ?> + '<br /></h3></div></body></html>'
```

I know that it is something to do with the **htmlTemplate** data.currentNewSize etc, but after tweaking my codes they are still showing undefined as shown in the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lies in the html code. As I have declared the array in sendHtmlEmail.gs, I did not call it correctly in my htmlTemplate.html.

In this line:

```
var returnData = [currentContact, currentNewSize, currentSub];
```

currentContact is in position 0, currentNewSize is in position 1 and so forth.

In the htmlTemplate.html, I need to replace this line:

```
+ <?= data.currentContact ?> + '<br />' + <?= data.currentNewSize ?> + '<br />' + <?= data.currentSub ?> + '<br /></h3></div></body></html>'
```

with this:

```
+ <?= returnData[0];?> + '<br />' + <?= returnData[1];?> + '<br />' + <?= returnData[2];?> + '<br /></h3></div></body></html>'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using an array in the method while the template is expecting an object.

Replace

```
    var returnData = [currentContact, currentNewSize, currentSub];
```

with

```
    var returnData = {currentContact: currentContact, currentNewSize: currentNewSize, currentSub: currentSub}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Amit, but I found the issue within the html code.